# Failed to connect host:80:Timed Out cURL php

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I have two applications. One is PHP and another is a Laravel app in which both are residing on different servers. I want to send data from the PHP application to the Laravel application, which I am doing using cURL. But it is throwing a 'Failed to connect: Timed out' error.

This is how I am sending the json-data using POST using cURL:

```
$url ='http://host_name/project/public/index.php/login';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$userdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}

echo $error_msg."<br>";

print_r(curl_getinfo());
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Failed to connect to host_name port 80: Timed out

   [url] => http://host_name/project/public/index.php/login
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 20.234
    [namelookup_time] => 0.015
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be a firewall issue.
it could be that port 80 is blocked by default. maybe change your request to https
it should solve the problem.
or if that fails, try putting this in your curl request
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)

if that also fails then you need to look at firewalls.

Comment: It could be a security risk.. but when he connects then at least he will know that it has to do with certificates  and can address that.